# HQL and inner classes (such as builders)

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider a `Result` DTO employing a builder pattern:

```
package com.example;
public class Result {
    int someValue;

    public static class Builder {
        private final Foo foo;
        private final Bar bar;

        public Builder(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        public Result build() {
            Result r = new Result();
            r.someValue = /* compute value based on supplied Foo and Bar */;
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to create the builder in an HQL query, such as:

```
select new Result.Builder(f, b) from Foo f, Bar b where ...
```

However, I end up with error

> Unable to locate class [com.example.Result.Builder]

One solution is to move the Builder to a separate class, but I like the Builder neatly packed with its entity.

**Is there a way, a syntax to make Hibernate recognize an inner class in the select clause?**

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3655

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ Oh... My google-fu was weak. However, this should be documented in a better place than a bugtracker comment.

Comment: found it from [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#mapping-declaration-class) ,It is acceptable for the named persistent class to be an interface. You can declare implementing classes of that interface using the <subclass> element. You can persist any static inner class. Specify the class name using the standard form i.e. e.g.Foo$Bar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out I found the solution in the end; The proper syntax is **fully qualified name with a `$` separator of inner class**, such as:

```
select new com.example.Result$Builder(f, b) from ...
```

Comment: And don't forget to make the inner class static ;)

Comment: Intelij may not resolve the symbol, but the application will start.