# Optimization in constructor parameters

Tags: java, sonarlint

I'm setting parameter directly into DTO which output we are getting from HQL

Below is the HQL:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.test.vos.CustomerDetails(firstname, lastName, address1, address2, address3, id, companyName, companyAddress, otherDetails) "
            + "FROM MstCustomer mc "
            + "INNER JOIN mc.mstAddress md "
            + "INNER JOIN mc.MstCompany mComapny "
            + "WHERE mc.mobileNo = :mobileNo ")
public List<CustomerDetails> getCustomerDetails(@Param("mobileNo") Integer mobileNo);
```

DTO :

```
public class CustomerDetails {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String address3;
    private String id;
    private String companyName;
    private String companyAddress;
    privatr String otherDetails;

    public CustomerDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String address1, String address2, String address3, String id, String companyName, String companyAddress, String otherDetails) {
        super();
        this.firstName = storeCode;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address1 = address1;
        this.address2 = address2;
        this.address3 = address3;
        this.id = id;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.companyAddress = companyAddress;
        this.otherDetails = otherDetails;
    }

    // Getter and Setter
}
```

> Above all code are working fine only issue is that its showing
>   Constructor has 9 parameters, which is greater than 7 authorized.

How to resolved that warning? What would be best approach?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Builder pattern](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/) to get one parameter (builder) in constructor

```
 private CustomerDetails(CustomerDetailsBuilder builder) {
    // ... set all fields using builder
 public static class CustomerDetailsBuilder
    //...update all parameters and build method
```

> This uses a additional class UserBuilder which helps us in building desired User object with all mandatory attributes and combination of optional attributes, without loosing the immutability.

For example

```
CustomerDetails customerDetails = new CustomerDetails.CustomerDetailsBuilder("Lokesh", "Gupta")
.address1("street 1")
.address2("Floor 2")
.address3("Fake address 1234")
.build();
```

Another option is lombok's [@AllArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/AllArgsConstructor.html)

> Generates an all-args constructor. An all-args constructor requires one argument for every field in the class.

Comment: How to call this from HQL?

Comment: Might be useful to check this up: https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder and add it to your project

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503917/hql-and-inner-classes-such-as-builders

Comment: @Repoker or just replace code with `@AllArgsConstructor`

Comment: Not getting proper example how to call builder method from HQL as I explained in the HQL

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty `SELECT new com.test.vos.CustomerDetails$CustomerDetailsBuilder(firstname, lastName, address1, address2, address3, id, companyName, companyAddress, otherDetails)`